# Android - call OnSaveInstanceState from another class than main

Tags: android

I am creating some EditTexts with button, I created a class which implements OnClickListener, and I want to save those EditTexts after screen rotation but they always disappear. I know that

1. Activity on rotation is destroyed and created again
2. I cant save EditText in Bundle since it does not implement Parcelable or something like that

So I tried to save at least their ID's and Text they have in them with the `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`
but it is not called because it is not in main class, but in another called ViewControl. I need to save some private variables (text and ids) so that is the reason why I have this method inside  my class. I tried to call this method from another onSaveInstance which is in main but no luck neither. Can you tell me some easy way to programatically create EditTexts one below another and KEEP them after screen rotation? I really cant find any easy way...

Main class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ViewControl vc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    vc = new ViewControl(this);


}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  vc.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

}
```

ViewControl class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class ViewControl extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Button btn;
    private RelativeLayout rl;
    private Activity act;
    private ArrayList<Integer> id;
    private ArrayList<String> userpath;
    private int lastId;

    public ViewControl(Activity activity) {

        this.act = activity;

        this.id = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        this.userpath = new ArrayList<String>();

        this.rl = (RelativeLayout)act.findViewById(R.id.layout);
        this.btn = (Button)act.findViewById(R.id.btn);

        this.id.add(Integer.valueOf(R.id.btn));
        this.btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(id.size() != 1)
            lastId = id.get(id.size() - 1);
        else
            lastId = R.id.btn;

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams par = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        par.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastId);

        EditText et = new EditText(act);

        et.setId(++lastId);
        id.add(Integer.valueOf(lastId));
        et.setText(Integer.toString(lastId));

        rl.addView(et, par);
        lastId = et.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
      savedInstanceState.putIntegerArrayList("ids", id);
      savedInstanceState.putStringArrayList("userpaths", userpath);
      savedInstanceState.putInt("lastId", lastId);

      Toast.makeText(act, "Onsave", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

      this.id = savedInstanceState.getIntegerArrayList("ids");
      this.userpath = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("userpaths");
      this.lastId = savedInstanceState.getInt("lastId");

      Toast.makeText(act, "Onrestore", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      for(int i = 0; i < id.size(); i++)
      {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams par = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            par.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastId);
            EditText et = new EditText(act);
            et.setId(this.id.get(i));
      }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calls are in the wrong order (both in `MainActivity` and `ViewControl`). First you should add your data, then pass the `Bundle` to `super` to save it (see the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState)). (Your `onRestoreInstanceState` is OK)

Comment: in main class I have onSaveInstace... I do not call any super, just vievcontrol.onSave... and then in ViewControls onSave i call super after asigning values but it does not work

Comment: @user3086577 Yes you do, at least in the code posted above, check MainActivity.onSaveInstanceState.

Comment: Sorry, I mean I edited code on pc as you say and it did not work, but then I realized it does, but It is not creating EditTexts, but it does save the values. So now I need to figure out how to do that. Do you have any good advice about recreating views created programatically?

Comment: @user3086577 If you created them from code, just run it again before restoring state (probably in onCreate or onResume).